# Change layout on Honeycomb with fragments

Tags: java, android, android-3.0-honeycomb, android-fragments, fragment

In my application, I have three tabs in the Action Bar.

```
Tab A : contains 2 fragments
Tab B : contains a WebViewFragment
Tab C : contains a WebViewFragment
```

Now, I use a global layout containing a LinearLayout.
I inflate the right layout in the LinearLayout according to the tab. But when I switch between B -> A, I get this error :

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Binary XML file line #8: Duplicate id 0x7f0a0002, tag null, or parent id 0xffffffff with another fragment for com.myapp.CategoriesFragment
```

What is the best solution to handle this ?

I have tried to removeAllViews / reAdd the layout, but I get this Exception :

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: The specified child already has a parent. You must call removeView() on the child's parent first.
```

I think I haven't choose the right solution.
Thanks for your answers

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can choose an inner container to hold the fragments
Refer to the sample layout below

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent">

    <LinearLayout android:id="@+id/fragment_container"    
          xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
</LinearLayout>
```